# Max heap in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, heap, max-heap

I am trying to write the function for creating a max heap in javascript 
My current code is

```js
var arr = [5, 9, 6, 7, 1, 3, 8]
var heap = []
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  addtoheap(arr[i]);
}

function addtoheap(term) {
  heap.push(term);

  if (heap.length > 1) {
    heapify(heap, (heap.length - 1))
  }
  console.log(heap);
}

function heapify(heap, i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    return;
  }
  if (heap[i] > heap[Math.floor(i / 2)]) {
    var temp = heap[i];
    console.log("Swapping" + heap[i] + "--" + heap[Math.floor(i / 2)]);
    heap[i] = heap[Math.floor(i / 2)];
    heap[Math.floor(i / 2)] = temp;
    return heapify(heap, Math.floor(i / 2));
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

And the output it gives is

> [ 5 ]
>   Swapping9--5
>   [ 9, 5 ]
>   Swapping6--5
>   [ 9, 6, 5 ]
>   Swapping7--6
>   [ 9, 7, 5, 6 ]
>   [ 9, 7, 5, 6, 1 ]
>   [ 9, 7, 5, 6, 1, 3 ]
>   Swapping8--6
>   Swapping8--7
>   [ 9, 8, 5, 7, 1, 3, 6 ]

Not sure what I am doing wrong here ,can someone please point out the mistake in my logic ?

Expected output : a max heap 
[9,7,8,5,1,3,6]

Comment: How do you know you are doing something wrong? You don't have `pop`.

Comment: The output is not what is expected  ,shouldn't the output me  [9,7,8,5,1,3,6]

Comment: pop from arr? @Amadan

Comment: Paste your expected output

Comment: The whole point of maxheap is that popping from it will always give the highest value. I.e. the test whether or not maxheap is correct is `let result = []; while (heap.length) { result.push(heappop(heap)); };` and then see if `result` is sorted. Your heap passes the test. There might be something subtly wrong that my test did not find, but at the first glance it's fine. Which is why I asked why you suspected an error.

Comment: I am basically trying trying to model the following program in javascript,
https://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-max-heap/

Comment: I am just trying to achieve a similar result ,

Comment: @TanmayBhattacharya, the reference that you have shared consider `base-1` addressing, but JS consider `base-0` addressing. Just change `Math.floor(i/2)` with `Math.floor((i-1)/2)` and give it a try.

Comment: @Prasun That worked !! thanks a bunch, cant believe I missed that .

Comment: @Amadan `[9,8,5,7,1,3,6]`, is not a valid heap. If you were to draw that tree, you'd see that 6 is a child of 5.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Prasun in the comments , JS uses indexes from 0 ,and the algorithm uses indexes starting from 1.
The following fix makes it work

```
function heapify(heap,i){
  if(i==0) return;
  if(heap[i] > heap[Math.floor((i-1)/2)]) { 
    var temp = heap[i];
    console.log("Swapping" +heap[i] +"--" + heap[Math.floor(i/2)]);
    heap[i] = heap[Math.floor((i-1)/2)];
    heap[Math.floor((i-1)/2)] = temp;
    return heapify(heap,Math.floor((i-1)/2));
  }
  else return;
}
```

Comment: Please, stop repeating yourself. Make a variable: `var parent = Math.floor((i-1)/2);`, and then use that in place of the expression. It makes your code a whole lot easier to read, and to modify. Plus, if you discover that you want to change the expression later, you only need to change it in one place.